# Genymotion player crashes when selecting the webcam option

Tags: linux, android-emulator, genymotion, webcam

Every time I select the webcam option on the Genymotion player, the title of the webcam option comes up, but then the hole emulator crashes.

I'm using the free version of Genymotion. I get this problem, regardless of the Android type or screen size etc.

**System Info:**

```
System:    Host: ALU Kernel: 5.10.7-3-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64 root=UUID=138895c2-cc5c-4591-bc68-fd58c682d6f3 rw quiet apparmor=1 
           security=apparmor resume=UUID=cbdc85f0-ae63-47be-89e8-038462fcc2f3 udev.log_priority=3 
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.20.5 tk: Qt 5.15.2 info: plank wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TU v: Lenovo ideapad 310-14IKB serial: <superuser required> Chassis: 
           type: 10 v: Lenovo ideapad 310-14IKB serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Torronto 4C2 v: NO DPK serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: 3JCN21WW date: 09/23/2016 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 23.6 Wh condition: 25.4/30.0 Wh (85%) volts: 8.6/7.4 model: SMP L15M2PB2 type: Li-poly 
           serial: 9238 status: Charging 
CPU:       Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check family: 6 
           model-id: 8E (142) stepping: 9 microcode: DE L2 cache: 4 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 23209 
           Speed: 1192 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1192 2: 1200 3: 1200 4: 1200 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: Split huge pages 
           Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
           Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
           Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
           Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:5916 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 920MX] vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia v: 460.32.03 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm 
           bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 10de:134f 
           Device-3: Chicony EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus ID: 1-4:2 chip ID: 04f2:b57d serial: 0001 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.10 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: loaded: modesetting display ID: :0 screens: 1 
           Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.2x8.0") s-diag: 414mm (16.3") 
           Monitor-1: eDP-1 res: 1366x768 hz: 60 dpi: 112 size: 309x173mm (12.2x6.8") diag: 354mm (13.9") 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.3 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_soc_skl 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:9d71 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.7-3-MANJARO 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: c8:5b:76:78:e3:cd 
           Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel 
           port: 4000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 168c:0042 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 58:00:e3:41:87:99 
           Device-3: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb bus ID: 1-7:4 chip ID: 0cf3:e500 
           IF-ID-1: vboxnet0 state: up speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 372.62 GiB used: 275.8 GiB (74.0%) 
           SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required. 
           ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37240G size: 223.57 GiB block size: physical: 512 B 
           logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: 50026B73801F8542 rev: 0102 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: Seagate model: ST9160412AS size: 149.05 GiB block size: physical: 512 B 
           logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: 5VGCALEC rev: HPM1 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 214.47 GiB size: 210.11 GiB (97.96%) used: 171.58 GiB (81.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
           maj-min: 8:2 
           ID-2: /boot/efi raw size: 300 MiB size: 299.4 MiB (99.80%) used: 312 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1 
           maj-min: 8:1 
Swap:      Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache pressure: 100 (default) 
           ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8.8 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (29.7%) priority: -2 dev: /dev/sda3 maj-min: 8:3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 265 Uptime: 8h 55m wakeups: 7 Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 6.19 GiB (80.6%) Init: systemd v: 247 Compilers: 
           gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 1676 apt: 3 pacman: 1660 lib: 464 flatpak: 0 snap: 13
```

**Last 20 lines of [genymotion-palyer.log](https://gofile.io/d/GPX5xB):**

```
2021-01-24T17:50:02+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress"" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2021-01-24T17:50:02+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:50:03+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress"" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2021-01-24T17:50:03+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:50:04+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress"" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2021-01-24T17:50:04+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:50:05+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress"" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2021-01-24T17:50:05+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:50:05+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] Device booted in 7474 ms
2021-01-24T17:50:05+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] "Notifying launchpad of status change: 8bb23482-88eb-41a1-b946-32593ca6654d ON"
2021-01-24T17:50:05+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress":5555" shell ("pm list packages")
2021-01-24T17:50:06+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("pm list packages")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:50:06+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] command: "/home/UserName/Software/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "ipaddress":5555" shell ("ls /data/.genymotion")
2021-01-24T17:50:06+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("ls /data/.genymotion")  - exit code: 0
2021-01-24T17:52:07+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] "Dummy camera" released by DeviceCameraPipe(0x1b42f30) count: 0
2021-01-24T17:52:07+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] "Dummy camera" acquired by CameraView(0x1b0d2a0) count: 1
2021-01-24T17:52:07+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] "Dummy camera" released by DeviceCameraPipe(0x1a35ff0) count: 1
2021-01-24T17:52:07+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] "Dummy camera" acquired by CameraView(0x192d2d0) count: 2
2021-01-24T17:52:07+05:00 [Genymotion Player:135865] [debug] Linux/Windows: media permissions are authorized by default
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by installing Genymotion as root,

```
~>>> sudo su
#>>> ./genymotion-installer.bin
```